# How to build pd series with user input iteratively one cell at a time?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, input, series

I am trying to categorize the remaining default cats in a pd series with my own input data:

```
ex_df = df[df['Cat_Self_Pred'] == 'Uncatted'][['Content','Amount','Cat_Self_Pred']] # shallow copy, so that the orig df is changed

for x in range(len(ex_df)): # how ever many this would be
    print(ex_df[['Content','Amount']].loc[x])
    ex_df['Cat_Self_Pred'].loc[x] = input()
```

So for the 'Un_catted' of df['Cat_Self_Pred'] I want to use a comprehension to input each of these one at a time based on 'Content' and 'Amount'

Even when I do the above, I get a warning about assigning values to a copy of the dataframe

Answer (score 1):

`ex_df` is a the result of 2 “indexing” operations on the dataframe, so assigning to it will always generate a warning. Basically it could be a `view` (what you call a shallow copy) or a `copy`.

See [`the pandas docs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html?highlight=settingwithcopywarning#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing) on this:

> assigning to the product of chained indexing has inherently unpredictable results.
> [...] it’s very hard to predict whether it will return a view or a copy (it depends on the memory layout of the array, about which pandas makes no guarantees)

The good news is that there is an easy and non-ambiguous way to do what you want to achieve.

Instead of creating a copy and iterating on its rows, you can iterate on the index and assign to `df` directly:

```
for idx in df.index[df['Cat_Self_Pred'] == 'Uncatted']:
    print(df.loc[idx, ['Content', 'Amount']])
    df.loc[idx, 'Cat_Self_Pred'] = input()
```

---

<sub>Also note you’re using `.loc[x]` but `x` is not an index, it’s the integer row number in ex_df − in that case you needed [`.iloc[x]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html).</sub>

Comment: That’s great @waltjva ! I see it’s your first question, so I’d suggest having a look at [what to do when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) which explains upvotes, downvotes, and accepted answers.